# If condition with group_concat in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table which has 2 columns empid & depid. This table does not have any primary key. Below is the data of the table.

```
+-------+-------+
| empid | depid |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |
|     1 |     2 |
|     1 |     3 |
|     1 |     4 |
|     2 |     1 |
|     2 |     2 |
|     2 |     3 |
|     2 |     4 |
+-------+-------+
```

Now to select all the depids for an employee I wrote below query.

```
select empid, group_concat(depid separator ':') from emp group by empid;
```

It is giving me expected output.

```
+-------+-----------------------------------+
| empid | group_concat(depid separator ':') |
+-------+-----------------------------------+
|     1 | 1:2:3:4                           |
|     2 | 1:2:3:4                           |
+-------+-----------------------------------+
```

Now I want select only those depids which are greater than 2. How can I use if with group_concat?

Comment: it's not group_concat's job to filter. just put `where depid > 2`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try as below :

```
SELECT empid, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(depid > 2, depid, NULL) SEPARATOR ':') 
FROM emp
GROUP BY empid;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow (and the Stack Exchange Network at large). Please edit this answer to include some explanation as to how it works and why it is a good idea.  Always answer with the intent to educate and empower not only the OP, but all future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select empid, group_concat(depid separator ':') 
from emp 
where depid > 2
group by empid
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow (and the Stack Exchange Network at large). Please edit this answer to include some explanation as to how it works and why it is a good idea.  Always answer with the intent to educate and empower not only the OP, but all future researchers.